# azure video streaming live how calculate the cost by size audience?

Tags: azure, video-streaming, streaming, azure-media-services

I want to make a live events with 100k viewers or more for 3 hours... How can I calculate the cost
I read documentation but the azure docs are quite ambiguous regarding the pricing

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut really where you can just enter an audience size and get a result - different factors will impact your approach including, bitrates, support level, number of events, redundancy and geo reach required etc.

A typical approach is to build a model, maybe using excel, and test different combinations and scenarios in the Azure online cost calculator.

You can then experiment with changing details like regions, support level etc to see the impact.